# Images from site asset library not displayed in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I have added a image in SiteAssets library. I have referred to that image in my aspx page. While redering page, image is not rendering.

Answer (score 3):

Few things you can check:

- Make sure the image is checked-in, approved, published.
- Make sure you can access the image when you directly hit the Image Url in the browser. like `http://server/SiteAssets/ImageName.ImageExtension`

Comment: i tried to open the image directly through Image url but it is not showing the image.

Comment: that means the URL is not correct, can you share the URL (hiding the server name, etc.)

Comment: the url is http://<server>/Energy/SiteAssets/SitePages/Home/ImpactModel.png i think it is something related to the .png extention

Comment: Can you try `http://<server>/Energy/SiteAssets/ImpactModel.png`

Comment: i already tried it is not displaying

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a permission issue: if the user who is displaying the page has not permission to the /Energy/SiteAssets/SitePages/Home/ then s/he won't see the image.
Move the image in an upper folder (/SiteAssets or /Images) which you are sure can be accessed by the user.
For sure no issues with .png!

Comment: just found following article http://johnmhester.wordpress.com/2013/05/21/png-files-not-showing-in-sharepoint-201o/. i edited and uploaded the image in jpeg format on the same path.it is getting displayed.it there any solution to upload CMYK images without editing

Comment: you can upload them for downloading purposes, but you won't display them in RGB.

Comment: Permissions ended up being my issue as well. I had recently modified some security settings in SharePoint admin center to "allow limited web only access" for unmanaged devices. I switched this back to "allow full access" and it works. What is odd however, is that the device I was on is fully compliant with intune. So im not sure why the device was seen as "unmanaged" to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue in SharePoint 2013, I resolved it by opening the image in Microsoft paint then saving as PNG was fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the issue isolated to images with the .PNG extension as SP13 needs 24 bit PNG. You would need an image editing software for that. Other image formats (.jpeg, bmp, etc) are being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

For me it has been the browser caching things.  If I go to the location where the image is deployed and then do a refresh, it will usually fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was interested in a solution for the same problem with SharePoint 2016.  Whether I tried inserting a JPG image into a Bulletin Board with a Link, From SharePoint, from Computer and neither of these options worked.  So then I did as Amal who earlier advised by changing the image from JPG to PNG - Afer loading the image again into the SharePoint Asset Library and using the From SharePoint 'insert image option'  I found this now worked for me! YAY!
Thankyou Amal!

Answer (score 0):

Add the image to the Style Library. For some weird reason images from the Site Assets library do not render...

Answer (score -2):

My understanding is that SharePoint supports only **HTTPS**. Therefore the URL should also `https://<server>/Energy/SiteAssets/SitePages/Home/ImpactModel.png`

Comment: Where have you gotten that understanding from? SharePoint on-prem surely supports both HTTP and HTTPS