# Sharepoint: inline image in email

Tags: sharepoint-online, email, csom, sharepoint-email, sputility

I am unable to add inline images in an `email`. The mail just show a square having a red cross inside it.

Is there a way to add inline images to email which needs to be sent from `SharePoint`.

**Updated:**

```
public static void SendMail(tenantContext,)
  {
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail(tenantContext, new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.EmailProperties()
            {
                From = from,
                To = email.to,
                Subject = "subject",
                Body = "hi <img src='image1.png'>",
            });
            tenantContext.ExecuteQuery();         
        }
```

Comment: Are you sending mail from designer?

Comment: No. I am using CSOM i.e SharePoint.EmailUtility class

Comment: when is it showing **a square having a red cross inside***? from browser or desktop mail client? or both?

Comment: Could you post your code here

Comment: @Unnie Updated the question

Comment: Check this: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/97351/images-from-site-asset-library-not-displayed-in-sharepoint I believe this is because permission issue. If image is getting accessed outside sharepoint environment it will not get displayed

Comment: @ps so this means it is not possible to add inline images using SP.Email Utility

Comment: For recipient email client/browser, src path should be a valid link to load image. You can upload image to a library that is accessible to recipient and give that path.

Also, inline images in mails can be sent by having encoded file content within the mail message of a multi-part (MIME) message. I am not sure if that is possible here.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code , the reason why you are getting red cross sqaure is either because the image source url  is wrong or the image cannot be retrieved because authentication is not done/user not having permission on site. But in any case loading image from the site in email is not good approach as the images won't be available during offline viewing of email or if the user who reads the email does not have permission on the site hosting the image.

You can alternatively try the below(Not tested with emails):

1. Convert image into Byte array.
2. [Inline Images with Data URLs](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/inline-images/) : Here you won't specify the url of the image in the src attribute , but you will embed the image in bytes into the html.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work :(

Comment: :-( What was the output you got?

Comment: In mail, images are embedded using a multi-part message specifying a cid, please check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312687/how-to-embed-images-in-email

Comment: @Prakash-CrowCanyon Sending Attachments are not available in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail

Comment: @Unnie, just as your answer, in multipart message, inline attachment content is part of message itself (Base 64 encoded). Mail clients look at cid in image source and find the corresponding part in message, decode the content, create a temporary file and replace the img source with that file path.

Comment: @Prakash-CrowCanyon Sounds good. I hope he tries out. It's handy if it worked :-)

Comment: @Prakash-CrowCanyon thanks for the pointers, but is there any way to create this template or I have to create it manually